# File download from web farm

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a project where we want to **provide link to download excel file**.
We are using **NLB** for load balancing,NLB cluster contains 3 machines.
constraint is that excel file to be downloaded is available on a single machine.
**How to ensure that HTTP request underneath will served from the same mahine?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot do that, as you thing.

Maybe the best solution is to create shared folder, and save all resources (files, images etc.) to that folder, on each server create virtual directory point to that folder, and use that path when providing link for downloading file.

Another solution is to use ip-based load balancer but this it is not recommended solution.

I hope you understand me, if not feel free to ask.